# What to set as "return" inside function when only handle something?

Tags: php, php-7

I have a data import class with many private functions. In most of functions there is json string handle to import data, so I don't have anything to return. Now what is the best practice to set as return of such functions?

Is `return;` or `return true;` correctly?

Comment: you don't have to set `return` in your function, it is optional.

Comment: If there is any possibility that something can fail, it's always useful to return a bool to say if the function has succeeded.

Comment: @NigelRen On and Off, because in case of something can fail - I'd rather like to have exception...

Comment: If something *fails* it should more likely throw an exception rather than return false. Return a useful value, or throw an exception. Only functions that perform checks: isValid(), isActive() etc ought to return booleans. IMO, obvs.

Comment: @VladimirKovpak There are failures and there are things that aren't correct - two very distinct things.  So it is a case of choosing the right approach for each instance.

Comment: In general, it's up to you to have `return true` or not... It won't provide any harm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, if you don't need to return any value - you must not use `return;` nor `return true;`.

In this case your function works not as pure function (it performs some mutation, or update some data in database or in cache or print data into output or stream etc) and it's perfectly ok!) But if you need this return for unit-tests - please don't do it, because it's ridiculous. Test your real behavior, check mutation, check output and so on and so forth...

Answer (score 0):

A return value is not required by a PHP function. It is however, best practice to add a docblock that sais so:

```
   /**
    * <function description?
    * 
    * @return void
    **/
    function doSomething()
    {
    }
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

> Note:
>   If the return is omitted the value NULL will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to use CQS (Command-query separation) approach. It states that every method should either be a command or a query, but not both. So the difference is:

1. Command - method that changes object state and should not return anything;
2. Query - method that return some data, but doesn't change object state.

   ```
   <?php

   class Foo
   {
       private $str = '';

       // this is a query
       public function getData() : string
       {
            return $this->str;
       }

       // this is a command
       public function setData(string $str) : void
       {
            $this->str = $str
       }
   }
   ```

   So, in your case functions for importing data are commands and should not return anything.